# iOS 6 SLComposeViewController for SLServiceTypeTwitter not able to cancel, edit or send

Tags: ios, ios6, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have some very simple code I am running in iOS 6, everything is working for all my devices and simulator, but one of my users (iPhone 3GS, iOS 6.1.2) is having issues.  When they call this code the SLComposeViewController shows the twitter dialog, but they can't cancel, edit or send.  They said the code works for Facebook.  So, I am at a loss.

Maybe making the SLComposeViewController a strong property?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
    SLComposeViewController *sc=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [sc setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Check out %@ app", [[ConfigUtil getConfig] objectForKey:@"app_title"]]];
    [sc addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[ConfigUtil getConfig] objectForKey:@"app_store_url"]]];
    [sc setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [self presentViewController:sc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a iOS issue with Twitter.  The user stated they could not send tweets from the Photos App also.  Going to put in a option to not include attachments and that may help things.